# How can change display value in Mat-Calandar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am preparing an attendance calendar in my project. I could able to display a mat-calendar and headlight dates with his/her attendance status.

Now, I would like to display `timeIn` & `timeOut` in respective dates in `mat-calendar`.

My server data looks like

```
attendance = [
    { attDate: '2020-04-01', timeIn: '09:00', timeOut: '21:00', status: null },
    { attDate: '2020-04-21', timeIn: '09:00', timeOut: '21:00', status: 'A' },
  ];
```

Date to display like

```
      1

09:00 - 21:00

     21

09:00 - 21:00
```

How can change display value in `mat-calendar`?

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-syerpr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is created for quick reference.

I am using `Angular9` and `Angular Material`

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I've found is to add the time using [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element. I used [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) css function to set the time content, but you can use css variables and [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) function as well.

```js
// app.component.ts
...

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ...

  constructor(
    private readonly elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const htmlElement: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    for (let [cellClass, date] of [
      ['holi-date', this.attendance[0]],
      ['green-date', this.attendance[1]]
    ] as const) {
      const dateElement = htmlElement.getElementsByClassName(cellClass).item(0);
      dateElement.setAttribute('data-date-time', `${date.timeIn} - ${date.timeOut}`);
    }
  }
```

```css
// styles.scss
...

[data-date-time]::after {
  content: attr(data-date-time);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-a6i1qo?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This solution seems to work for me but `['holi-date', this.attendance[0]],` cannot be constant, as attendance rows are dynamic. Is there a way to change this to dynamic?

Comment: @Ramesh Sure, you can execute this code at any time, I mean `dateElement.setAttribute(...)` and as many times as you want, there're no restrictions.

Comment: I could not success in modifying it, can you update your link with few more dates?

Comment: @Ramesh [Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-apv68w) an updated sample.

Comment: For more clarity I have updated your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-7jm2kr?file=app/app.component.ts). And given my requirement in more detailed in `updateTime()`